# How to override core taxonomy/term/% with a view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have enabled the taxonomy/term/% view provided by the Views module but taxonomy term views are still handled by the core. Modifications has no effects and hooks such as  `hook_views_pre_render()` are not invoked.

However, views explicitly specifying a term such as taxonomy/term/5 work.

Do you have any idea on how I can override the core default taxonomy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had the [Taxonomy View Integrator (TVI)](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) module enabled. By default, if no override is set it invokes the core term page, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The [Taxonomy views integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) module can help you; it allows selective overriding of taxonomy terms and/or vocabulary with the view of your choice.

Comment: TVI was the origin of the problem. Your answer helped me a lot as I probably would not have thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the default view before it will take over. Add your customizations (for example, a field) to the taxonomy display, and save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the default display, that's how I realized the view was not even called